# .click() Event dont get executed

Tags: jquery

I have a link on my site which opens a modal dialog with the login form. I use AJAX to send the login data to the server and but somehow, the .click() event doesn't work. I guess its because I load the html with .html().

Here's the code:

```
$('#loginLink').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('<div id="loginContainer" title="Login"></div>')
            .html('<?php echo str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "", $this->element("ajax/login")); ?>')
            .dialog({
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                position: 'top'
            });
        });
        $('#UserLoginForm input[type=submit]').click(function() {
            e.preventDefault();

            var form = $('#UserLoginForm').serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/login',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: form,
                beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                    $("#loginContainer .ajaxloader").show();
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var message = $("#loginContainer > .flashMessage");

                    if(data.status == 'success') {
                        location.href = '/account';
                    } else {
                        message.text(data.msg);
                        message.show();
                    }
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#loginContainer .ajaxloader').hide();
                    $('#loginContainer > .flashMessage').text('There was an error.').show();
                },
                complete: function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                    $("#loginContainer .ajaxloader").hide();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

This part loads the content from a file:

```
<?php echo str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "", $this->element("ajax/login")); ?>
```

And outputs:

```
<div class="flashMessage fail"></div><form action="/login" controller="users" id="UserLoginForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"><div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/></div><div class="input text required"><label for="UserEmail">E-Mail</label><input name="data[User][email]" style="width: 267px;" maxlength="64" type="text" id="UserEmail"/></div><div class="input password required"><label for="UserPassword">Password</label><input name="data[User][password]" style="width: 267px;" type="password" id="UserPassword"/></div><div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Login"/></div></form><div class="ajaxloader"><img src="/img/icons/ajax-loader.gif" alt="" /></div><div class="clear" style="line-height: 8px;">&nbsp;</div>
```

Everything works fine except the .click() part to send the AJAX request :/ Im not that good in Javascript, so I don't know what exactly the error is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Any dynamic contents inserted into dom should use `.on` ( jQuery v1.7) or  `.live/.delegate` ( before jQuery 1.7).
2. You are missing quotes inside the attribute selector..
3. As in other post, you missed to pass 'e' (event) argument.

Using .on or .delegate is recommended over .live.

Using .on [recommended]

```
      $('#loginContainer').on('click',  '#UserLoginForm input[type="submit"]', function (e) {
```

Using .live,

```
      $('#UserLoginForm input[type="submit"]').live('click', function(e) {
```

Using .delegate [recommended]

```
      $('#loginContainer').delegate('#UserLoginForm input[type="submit"]', 'click', function (e) {
```

Comment: Man thank you really =) The problem is solved, thanks to everyone who helped!

Comment: What is the 2nd parameter? why not just `'click', function(e)`?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the "e" in the `function()`.

Comment: Thank you, shame on me that I forgot that x_X

Answer (score 0):

do you bind you click action via `.click()` IF you do that, change it to `.on("click",function(){});`

Simply because the element is inserted to the DOM after it has been fully loaded. so your .click doesn't take effect because the element isn't available at this point !

EDIT:
You didn't pass the e for the event !

Comment: Hey, thank you for the tip. But unfortunatley it doesn't work. I add the "e" to the functions parameter and use .on() instead of .click() but when I click on the submit button, it still refers to the script instead of using the .ajax() function :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the delegate method to wire your event up.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').delegate('#yourbuttonid', 'click', yourbutton_onclick_function);
});
```

The delegate method will wire your click event to your button no matter when it is added to the page.

So replace this...

```
$('#loginLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('<div id="loginContainer" title="Login"></div>')
        .html('<?php echo str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "", $this->element("ajax/login")); ?>')
        .dialog({
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            position: 'top'
        });
    });
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').delegate('#loginLink', 'click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('<div id="loginContainer" title="Login"></div>')
            .html('<?php echo str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "", $this->element("ajax/login")); ?>')
            .dialog({
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                position: 'top'
            });
        });
    });
});
```